# How to watch a Zebrafish embryo in detail?

Tags: genetics, lab-techniques, animal-models

How much microscope zoom would I need to watch the development of a Zebrafish embryo in certain detail? Thanks guys!

Comment: It might help if you clarify what you mean by "certain detail".

Comment: Observing the development of cord and eyes would be a good start.

Answer (score 2):

From personal experience, it should be sufficient to observe zebrafish at 10-20x magnification for broad structural changes during development.  If your microscope has a 10x eyepiece, then that would be 1-2x zoom. If you are observing sub-cellular changes, you would benefit from higher magnification.